# Using more than one screen for an issue based on which group a user belongs to

Tags: jira

My problem is that I'm trying to hide certain fields for issues in a project based on which group the user belongs to. Is it possible to have more than one screen for an issue, and depending on which group the user belongs to they get shown a different screen with different fields?

Thanks

Comment: Everything is possible :) which Jira version?

Comment: The Jira version is 4.2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Behaviours Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.plugin.Behaviours) to hide/show fields according to users permissions, example:

```
FormField someField = getFieldByName("select example")
def user = componentManager.getJiraAuthenticationContext().getLoggedInUser()
if (user == 'John') {
    someField.setHidden(true)
}
```

or, according to user's group:

```
FormField someField = getFieldByName("select example")
def user = componentManager.getJiraAuthenticationContext().getLoggedInUser()
def isAdmin = componentManager.getUserUtil().getGroupNamesForUser(user.name).contains("jira-administrators")
if (! isAdmin) {
    someField.setHidden(true)
}
```